# input's value isn't set by JavaScript (or is it?)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-4.0, code-behind

I'm trying to pass information from js to codebehind. When setting a breakpoint at the end of the js - The (Firefox) **debugger** (-js) shows me that an `input`'s value *has* been set, while the (Firefox) **Inspector** (-html) shows it *hasn't*. When reaching the **codebehind** - it *hasn't* been set. Why?

**js** to set the value and click a button that will then call the codebehind:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doit(s, input, button)
    {
        var i = document.getElementById(input);
        i.innerHTML = s;
        var b = document.getElementById(button);
        b.click();
    }       
</script>
```

**html** with hidden input and button (for calling the codebehind) and a button to begin all of this, and a div to show the result:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<div style="display: none;">
    <input id="info" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
</div>
<div id="result" runat="server">
</div>
```

**C# codebehind** to call the js, and to show the result:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    Type pageType = GetType();
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(
        GetType(),
        "aName",
        "doit('abc', '" + info.ClientID + "','" + Button2.ClientID + "');", 
        true);
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    result.InnerText = info.Value;
}
```

Comment: Input elements don't have any innerHtml... Are you sure you want that instead of `value` attribute?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You were the first to spot my mistake. You can transform your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `value` property of input instead of `innerHTML`

*Change*

```
i.innerHTML = s;
```

*To*

```
i.value = s;
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `value` to set the value of an input:

```
function doit(s, input, button) {
    document.getElementById(input).value = s;
    var b = document.getElementById(button);
    b.click();
}
```